# How to run Javascript program in browser instead of console when using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prompt

I am working on a simple enough beginner tutorial in Javascript in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019, but am encountering an error when trying to utilize the prompt() function. My problem is as follows:

```
'use strict';
var msg = 'You entered:';
let promptInput = prompt("What would you like to enter");
console.log(msg);
console.log(promptInput);
```

However, and I suspect this is because the program is running in the console and not a browser, I am getting a prompt() function not defined error.

[Console Error Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAZ7o.png)

How might I fix this? Is it because I am using node.js that the program runs in the console and not a browser?

Comment: Your console shows "node.exe", so yeah, it's node, which doesn't have the browser API. I'll make an opinionated suggestion: switch to vscode, setting up a chrome debugger there is quite easy.

Comment: Thanks, I'm now of a happy new user of vscode!

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a solution, but not a complete fix to my problem. I learned that there is a way to run JS code in a the most common browsers (Edge, Chrome, Firefox) using what is called 'Developer Tools'. You can find 'Developer Tools' in the Settings --> More Tools --> Developer Tools dropdown menu on Microsoft edge or by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+I. Once you have the 'Developer Tools' sidebar open, navigate to the console tab, clear the console of any existing code, and paste your JS code into the console. Then, press enter, and you will see your code manifest itself within your open browser window. I hope this helps, thanks.